# How to display content from many-to-one relationship

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, many-to-one

So I'm going crazy trying to figure out what seems like it should be a dead-simple task.

I'm making a portfolio site. It has 2 models, Project and Image. Project contains most of the data for each project, while Image is in a many-to-one relationship to supply Project with a variable number of images per Project.

On the homepage, I would like to show each project in its own section, and the images for each project in their respective sections. Currently, I have the projects displayed, and I'm able to display all the images from the database under each section:

```
  {% for image in images.all %}
              <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt="">
          {% endfor %}
```

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to display just the images for each respective section in the template, despite diving through pages of documentation, stack answers, and web posts.

I've seen so many examples of how to query a model in this type of relationship from the views/model layers, but none of these seem to work in the template layer. I also don't know how I would perform the query on a different layer and send that through to the template, if I were to go that route.

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
title = models.TextField()
year = models.CharField(max_length=20)
tech = models.TextField()
role = models.TextField()
description = models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Image(models.Model):
name = models.TextField()
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/project_images/')
project = models.ForeignKey(to=Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
home = Home.objects
projects = Project.objects
images = Image.objects

return render(request, 'portfolio/home.html', {'home': home,
                'projects': projects, 'images': images})
```

template

```
{% for project in projects.all %}
<h2>{{ project.title }}</h2>
{{ project.tech|linebreaks }}

     {% for image in project.image_set.all %}
              <img src="{{ image.project_image.url }}" alt="">
     {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi,I suggest that you change the relationship the other way, I mean that in the project model you must have a foreign key to Images, then you could use a ListView to Display the projects and the a DetailView to see the Images inside that project

Answer (score 1):

The approach in your code is correct. Just change `{{ image.project_image.url }}` to `{{ image.image.url }}`

You might expect the template engine to throw some kind of error if a template variable does not exist, but it does not.

Per the behavior described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/api/#how-invalid-variables-are-handled):

You can use the `string_if_invalid` configuration parameter to surface these instances (by default it uses the empty string):

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
    ,
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'string_if_invalid': 'Invalid variable: %s' if DEBUG else '',
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

The above sets the invalid string to indicate the name of the invalid variable only if running in DEBUG mode. This would result in the following in your rendered html:

`<img src="Invalid variable: image.project_image.url" alt="">`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property to your project model and Add a "related_name" to project ForeignKey

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
   title = models.TextField()
   year = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   tech = models.TextField()
   role = models.TextField()
   description = models.TextField()

   @property
   def get_images(self):
        return self.images.all()



class Image(models.Model):
   name = models.TextField()
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/project_images/')
   project = models.ForeignKey(to=Project, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then in the template you can call the project object to get all images for that project object using the property we defined

template

```
{% for image in  project.get_images %}
   #DO Something for each image
{% endfor %}
```